# How to JSON.stringify multiple objects returned from Loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, object

Here is my mvc code,  I want to add multiple travelers objects to `travelers` array which are generated in a loop and then `JSON.stringify` them,

```
return amadeus.booking.flightOrders.post(
        JSON.stringify({
          'data':{
            'type': 'flight-order',
            'flightOffers': [response.data.flightOffers[0]],  
           'travelers':[{
              "id": 1,
              "name": {
                "firstName": req.body.firstname,
                "lastName": req.body.lastname
              },
              "gender": req.body.gender,
              "contact": {
                "emailAddress": req.body.emailaddress,
                "phones": [{
                  "deviceType": req.body.devicetype,
                  "countryCallingCode": req.body.countrycallingcode,
                  "number": req.body.number
                }]
              },
              "documents": [{
                "documentType": req.body.documentype,
                "birthPlace": req.body.birthplace,
                "issuanceLocation": req.body.issuancelocation,
                "issuanceDate": req.body.issuancedate,
                "number": req.body.p_number,
                "expiryDate": req.body.expirydate,
                "issuanceCountry": req.body.issuancecountry,
                "validityCountry": req.body.validitycountry,
                "nationality": req.body.nationality,
                "holder": true
              }]
            }]
        } 
      })
      );
```

I there a simple way to achieve that?

Comment: JSON.stringify is a function. it expects a value to be passed to it. There's nothing stopping you from building that value outside of the JSON.stringify call's argument list.

Comment: You can add multiple travelers to the travelers array and stringify it, it has nothing to do with JSON.stringify

Comment: @MetaPakistani could you guide, me how can i do it?

Comment: @aghahamza Check explaination in answer

Comment: @MetaPakistani is there any way to insert travelers through loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JSON.stringify` converts a JS object to a string. It does not control or require any specifications for the object's structure in general.

In your case, you can simply add multiple data objects to your travelers' array e.g

```
return amadeus.booking.flightOrders.post(
    JSON.stringify({
      'data':{
        'type': 'flight-order',
        'flightOffers': [response.data.flightOffers[0]],  
       'travelers':[{
          "id": 1,
          "name": {
            "firstName": req.body.firstname,
            "lastName": req.body.lastname
          },
          "gender": req.body.gender,
          "contact": {
            "emailAddress": req.body.emailaddress,
            "phones": [{
              "deviceType": req.body.devicetype,
              "countryCallingCode": req.body.countrycallingcode,
              "number": req.body.number
            }]
          },
          "documents": [{
            "documentType": req.body.documentype,
            "birthPlace": req.body.birthplace,
            "issuanceLocation": req.body.issuancelocation,
            "issuanceDate": req.body.issuancedate,
            "number": req.body.p_number,
            "expiryDate": req.body.expirydate,
            "issuanceCountry": req.body.issuancecountry,
            "validityCountry": req.body.validitycountry,
            "nationality": req.body.nationality,
            "holder": true
          }]
        },{
          "id": 2,
          "name": {
            "firstName": req.body.firstname,
            "lastName": req.body.lastname
          },
          "gender": req.body.gender,
          "contact": {
            "emailAddress": req.body.emailaddress,
            "phones": [{
              "deviceType": req.body.devicetype,
              "countryCallingCode": req.body.countrycallingcode,
              "number": req.body.number
            }]
          },
          "documents": [{
            "documentType": req.body.documentype,
            "birthPlace": req.body.birthplace,
            "issuanceLocation": req.body.issuancelocation,
            "issuanceDate": req.body.issuancedate,
            "number": req.body.p_number,
            "expiryDate": req.body.expirydate,
            "issuanceCountry": req.body.issuancecountry,
            "validityCountry": req.body.validitycountry,
            "nationality": req.body.nationality,
            "holder": true
          }]
        },{
          "id": 3,
           .
           .
           .
        },{
          "id": 4,
           .
           .
           .
        }]
      } 
    })
  );
```

and `JSON.stringify` will convert whole object to string.

To loop on data and add the travelers array, one approach will be:

```
const travelers = [];
for(let i=0;i<10;i++){

   travelers.push({});
}
```

and then

```
return amadeus.booking.flightOrders.post(
    JSON.stringify({
      'data':{
        'type': 'flight-order',
        'flightOffers': [response.data.flightOffers[0]],  
       'travelers': travelers
      } 
    })
  );
```

Comment: is there any way to insert travelers through loop?